# Slim app directory structure - Apache rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, backbone.js, slim

Instead of official [dir structure](http://docs.slimframework.com/#Route-URL-Rewriting):

```
/path/www.mysite.com/
public_html/ <-- Document root!
    .htaccess
    index.php <-- I instantiate Slim here!
lib/
    Slim/ <-- I store Slim lib files here!
```

I plan to use:

```
/
api/
   Slim/
   .htaccess
   app.php    <-- Slim app
webapp/
   client-site/
   scripts/
   .../
.htaccess
index.html
other-static.html
```

with the following `.htaccess` rewrites:

```
/.htaccess
#e.g. for wines API (http://localhost/wines)
RewriteRule ^wines$ api/wines [QSA]

/api/.httaccess
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ app.php [QSA,L]
```

And where app.php defines Slim routing.

Why the /wines is not picked up by Slim?

Example is on [GitHub](https://github.com/uicoded/uic-winecellar-slim-backbone)

Comment: Please share an example URL, one that you'd like Slim to serve, your route definition that matches your example URL, and your apache vhost.

Comment: see also: https://github.com/uicoded/uic-winecellar-slim-backbone/issues/1

Comment: I want the server to serve `http://server/wines`, the Slim router is set $app->get('/wines', 'getWines'); and returns 404 (Slim 404). The Slim works without the rewrite, i.e. `http://server/api/wines` works. vhost is via simlink, the docroot is 2 levels bellow (`http://server/GIT/uic-winecellar-slim-backbone/wines` I don't know if it can affect Slim. There is GitHub issue documented and htaccess files with comments.